# Use and over use of static variables

Tags: c++, game-loop

Is it recommended to use static variables where ever I am comfortable with?

Because I tend to use it more often now.  Is there any thing like using static variables is a bad practice or it will fill up the memory quickly?

Currently I am doing small games with c++. So to maintain some states like jump position and animation time I have to use static variables in a function and that function will be called multiple times in a loop. So static variables will do that Job. Is there any oo patterns to get over this problem?

```
void jumpit(){
    static int jump ;
    if( !jump && pressed)
          jump=1;
    if (jump)
         obj.y++;
}
```

And in the loop I will call this to get the Job done..do we have any better idea to do the same??

Comment: Sorry for bad formatting of the code ..I am typing it in android app

Comment: Using statics willy-nilly is really convenient, right until you paint yourself into a corner with it.

Comment: Thank you...how do I become good game developer...I am not interested using game engine though I would consider using it...I want to go from ground up

Comment: You become a good game developer by becoming a good developer, and then learning the game industry's best practices.

Comment: I would face problems if I use this function for 2 or more objects to make it jump

Comment: Yes. If you have state, encode it separately, and pass that to your functions. Read up on OOP.

Comment: Where do I learn best practices..Is it what those books like game patterns talk about?

Comment: I would consider using std::map for simplicity..and it's already an oop know

Comment: How do I know the reason for down voting my question

Comment: Probably. I never read it, so I can't comment as to it's merits. But it seems decent.
A map would be simple, but it would not be the fastest data structure around, which games often depend on. If you use c++, read up on Effective C++, Effective STL and take a look at the EASTL library.
You were probably downvoted because the question doesn't fit the sites format. You can read about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).
Also, comments are not for extended discussion. This is not a forum.

Comment: Uhh EASTAL I would look at it

Comment: I don't get any relevant results for eastal library..what is that all about

Comment: I had a typo (which I corrected). It's [EASTL](https://github.com/electronicarts/EASTL)

Comment: How to have a personal chat in stack overflow...man your amazing..just wanna text you

Comment: *"Is it recommended to use static variables where ever I am comfortable with?"* - The more experienced you become, the more you can rely on your gut instincts. *"Is there any thing like using static variables is a bad practice or it will fill up the memory quickly?"* - It has nothing to do with filling up memory. It's a question of program semantics and coding style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "obj" could keep track of its own state.

A free standing jumpit function could be implemented as:

```
void jumpit(Object& obj, bool pressed)
{
        if( !obj.jump && pressed)
              obj.jump = true;
        if (obj.jump)
             obj.y++;
}
```

Or it might be better to implement jumpit as part of "Object"

It is almost never a good idea to keep state in a function.

Comment: I got that. .but these are similar situations that I use static variables